# How to get latest 5 values from table in random manner in yii query syntax

Tags: yii

I have used this way

```
$blog = Yii::app()->db
  ->createCommand()
  ->from('blog')
  ->Where('status=:status',array(':status'=>'Active'))
  ->limit(array('0,5'))
  ->order(array('RAND()'))
  ->queryAll();
```

but its not working properly..

Answer (score 1):

`RAND()` have to be in CDbExpression

```
$blog = Yii::app()->db
  ->createCommand()
  ->from('blog')
  ->Where('status=:status',array(':status'=>'Active'))
  ->limit(array('0,5'))
  ->order(new CDbExpression("RAND()"))
  ->queryAll();
```